# Wicket - IValidator not calling validate when TextField is empty

Tags: java, forms, validation, wicket

I have a class that implements the `IValidator`. I add this validator class to my `TextField`, and the overrided method `validate(Invalidatable<T>)` is called. However, if the `TextField`is empty, the method is not called, and the validation does not occurs. Why is this happening? Is this expected behavior?

**Validator Class**

```
public class CorporateNameValidator implements IValidator<String> {

        private static final String ERROR_EMPTY = "Error";

        @Override
        public void validate(IValidatable<String> validatable) {

            //Method not called when TextField has blank value.

            final String name = validatable.getValue();

            info("NAME: " + name);
        }
    }
```

**Instantiating TextField**

`corporateNameInput = new TextField<String>(CORPORATE_NAME_INPUT_ID, new PropertyModel<String>(this, ""));`

**Setting TextField Properties**

`corporateNameInput.add(new CorporateNameValidator());`
`corporateNameInput.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);`

And then I add the TextField to the Form.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the JavaDoc of `IValidator`:

> Interface representing a validator that can validate an `IValidatable` object.
>
> Unless the validator implements the `INullAcceptingValidator` interface as well,
>   Wicket will not pass `null` values to the `IValidator#validate(IValidatable)` method.

It is as designed, and you should implement `INullAcceptingValidator` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I should have read the docs with more attention, sorry :S